# How to use -XX:+PrintGCDetails

Tags: java, garbage-collection, web-config, jvm-arguments

I want printout GC details using the command line argument.

**Currently i am using it like :**

```
java -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7888 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=FALSE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=FALSE -Dlogging.config=../config/log4j.xml -Dproject.config=../config -Dspring.config.location=../config/application.properties,../config/${ENV}/db-config.properties,../config/sql-config.properties,../config/error-config.properties,../config/message-config.properties,../config/validation-config.properties -jar ../lib/project.jar "
```

I want to know where I can see the results of GC LOGS. Am I writing in right place for GC logs?

Thanks

Comment: Define "right place". With the current setup you should see a `gc.log` file under the same folder you're running the java executable from. You can also define an absolute path as the argument value for `-Xloggc`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String gclogs = System.getProperty("Xloggc");`

Answer (score 0):

Option `-Xloggc:gc.log` tells it to write to a file called `gc.log` in the current directory.

`-verbose:gc` is ignored when `-Xloggc` is specified.
Don't know if `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` is ignored too, but it probably is.